# How calculate intersection directly without Stokes' theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

Calculate the line integral directly without Stokes' theorem:
\begin{gather*}
\oint_\gamma \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*}
\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)=(2z-3y) {\hat{\mathbf{i}}} + (3x-z){\hat{\mathbf{j}}} + (y-2x){\hat{\mathbf{k}}}
\end{gather*}
$\gamma$ is the intersection of the sphere 
\begin{gather*}
x^2+y^2+z^2=1
\end{gather*}
and the plane
\begin{gather*}
x+y+z=0
\end{gather*}
**Solution:**
First the intersection:
\begin{gather*}
z=\pm \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} \\
z=-x-y
\end{gather*}
Solve with the positive square root:
\begin{gather*}
\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} =-x-y \\
1-x^2-y^2=(-x-y)^2 = x^2+y^2+2xy\\
\iff \\
2x^2+2y^2+2xy=1
\end{gather*}
And here I'm stuck because I can't eliminate x or y in the last equation ...

Comment: The intersection is a curve. You won't be able to eliminate two out of three variables.

Comment: Okey, so it's not possible to parametrize the intersection? Or should I parametrize $2x^2+2y^2+2xy=1$?

Comment: Sure it is. In the $xy$ plane it's an ellipse, rotated $\pi/4$ radians. Start with the ellipse $x^2/3+y^2=1$ and hit it with a transformation matrix. See  [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7Bcos(t)%7D,%7B1%2Fsqrt(3)*sin(t)%7D%7D*%7B%7Bcos(pi%2F4),+-sin(pi%2F4)%7D,%7Bsin(pi%2F4),cos(pi%2F4)%7D%7D)

Comment: Thanks! Btw, how did you find the rotation $\pi/4$ radians?